# How do I prevent application from auto-launching when logging in via SSH

Tags: centos

Each time I login via SSH, the Mutt automatically opens. How do I prevent it from doing so?

[image: Mutt opens upon logging in via SSH]

I have compared my settings on my staging server to the live server and cannot spot the difference.

`vim .muttrc` returns:

```
#======================================================#
# Boring details
set realname ="Name"
set from = name@gmail.com
set use_from = yes
set envelope_from ="yes"
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"

# If not set in environment variables:
set spoolfile = /var/spool/mail/name

#======================================================#
# Folders
set folder="~/Mail"                # Mailboxes in here
set record="+sent"                 # where to store sent messages
set postponed="+postponed"         # where to store draft messages
set move=no                        # Don't move mail from the spool.

#======================================================#
# Watch these mailboxes for new mail:
mailboxes ! +Fetchmail +slrn +mutt
set sort_browser=alpha    # Sort mailboxes by alpha(bet)

#======================================================#
# Order of headers and what to show
hdr_order Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer \
To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:
ignore *
unignore Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer  \
To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:

#======================================================#
# which editor do you want to use?
# vim of course!
set editor="vim -c 'set tw=70 et' '+/^$' "
set edit_headers          # See the headers when editing

#======================================================#
# Aliases

set sort_alias=alias     # sort aliases in alpha order by alias name

#======================================================#
# Odds and ends
set markers          # mark wrapped lines of text in the pager with a +
set smart_wrap       # Don't wrap mid-word
set pager_context=5  # Retain 5 lines of previous page when scrolling.
set status_on_top    # Status bar on top.
push <show-version>  # Shows mutt version at startup
```

Comment: Sounds like you have it in your shell's startup init file (e.g., ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc).  If so, remove it.

Comment: `vim ~/.bashrc` revealed a line that referenced mutt and a few other lines that threw errors during login. Thanks for pointing out these files and their purpose.

Comment: Disregard - I was in the process of editing this post when you submitted your initial comment.